# How to split large wikipedia dump .xml.bz2 files in Python?

Tags: python, xml, mediawiki

I am trying to build a offline wiktionary using the wikimedia dump files (.xml.bz2) using Python. I started with [this](http://users.softlab.ece.ntua.gr/~ttsiod/buildWikipediaOffline.html) article as the guide. It involves a number of languages, I wanted to combine all the steps as a single python project. I have found almost all the libraries required for the process. The only hump now is to effectively split the large .xml.bz2 file into number of smaller files for quicker parsing during search operations.

I know that bz2 library exists in python, but it provides only compress and decompress operations. But I need something that could do something like `bz2recover` does from the command line, which splits large files into a number of smaller junks.

One more important point is the splitting shouldn't split the page contents which start with `<page>` and ends `</page>` in the xml document that has been compressed.

Is there a library previously available which could handle this situation or the code has to be written from scratch?(Any outline/pseudo-code  would be greatly helpful).

Note: I would like to make the resulting package cross-platform compatible, hence couldn't use OS specific commands.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

At last I have written a Python Script myself:

```
import os
import bz2

def split_xml(filename):
    ''' The function gets the filename of wiktionary.xml.bz2 file as  input and creates
    smallers chunks of it in a the diretory chunks
    '''
    # Check and create chunk diretory
    if not os.path.exists("chunks"):
        os.mkdir("chunks")
    # Counters
    pagecount = 0
    filecount = 1
    #open chunkfile in write mode
    chunkname = lambda filecount: os.path.join("chunks","chunk-"+str(filecount)+".xml.bz2")
    chunkfile = bz2.BZ2File(chunkname(filecount), 'w')
    # Read line by line
    bzfile = bz2.BZ2File(filename)
    for line in bzfile:
        chunkfile.write(line)
        # the </page> determines new wiki page
        if '</page>' in line:
            pagecount += 1
        if pagecount > 1999:
            #print chunkname() # For Debugging
            chunkfile.close()
            pagecount = 0 # RESET pagecount
            filecount += 1 # increment filename           
            chunkfile = bz2.BZ2File(chunkname(filecount), 'w')
    try:
        chunkfile.close()
    except:
        print 'Files already close'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # When the script is self run
    split_xml('wiki-files/tawiktionary-20110518-pages-articles.xml.bz2')
```

Comment: This is great. If you want to use each chunk with wiki parsing tools make sure to add closing tags for "mediawiki" at the end of each XML file as well. Then it works fine.

        </revision>
      </page>
    </mediawiki>

Comment: The code works for python 2 but in python3, the comparison need to be replaced with `if b'</page>' in line`

Answer (score 1):

well, if you have a command-line-tool that offers the functionality you are after, you can always wrap it in a call using the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module

Comment: But I want to make sure the result package is cross-platform compatible.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to mention it. Edited the original question now.

Answer (score 0):

The method you are referencing is quite a dirty hack :)

I wrote a offline Wikipedia Tool, and just Sax-parsed the dump completely. The throughput is usable if you just pipe the uncompressed xml into stdin from a proper bzip2 decompressor. Especially if its only the wiktionary.

As a simple way for testing I just compressed every page and wrote it into one big file and saved the offset and length in a cdb(small key-value store). This may be a valid solution for you.

Keep in mind, the mediawiki markup is the most horrible piece of sh*t I've come across in a long time. But in case of the wiktionary it might me feasible to handle.

Comment: While parsing the entire dump by the sax way might be simpler, the problem of indexing and searching a large file is difficult/taxing. Regarding the Mediawiki markup [this](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Alternative_parsers) might help you. ;)

Comment: For fulltext search use xapian/lucene (I've also seen a pure python engine), it ends up being not very difficult. - lucene is awesome btw :) - And I pretty much tried all of the parsers/renderers, you still have to handle language specific hacks and localisation, Wikipedia specific hacks, and a lot of other stuff. The MediaWiki ecosystem is awfully, lets say, improperly done.

Comment: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/wikidump/0.1.2 just found this one, looks like it could do some work for you.